# ListView navigation using Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, routes

I am trying to figure out how to make my application a Shell application.

This is my shell.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Project.View"
   x:Class="Project.AppShell">
<ShellContent Title=""
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"/>
<ShellContent Title=""
             ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ListView}" 
              Route="StockListView"/>

</Shell>
```

I am having trouble to make sense of the routing, my goal is to make routing from the listview to another view, like below.

```
MainView
ListView
    ViewItem
```

I don't find it clear how to implement this, since the listview is not one of the three main hierachical objects, at least not obvious for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction
. I can get it to work by changing the page from my viewmodel that is connected to my listview.

```
App.Current.Mainpage = View
```

But it feels like I am mixing things up and that it should be possible to use Shell routing in some way, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to register the route, you can register the route in the xaml page or register the route in the back-end code.

   For more information you can refer to: [Register routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes).
2. After registering the route you can use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//ListView/ViewItem");` code to make the call elegantly.

   Please take care of the use of routes multiple levels(route hierarchy).

   For the detailed usage of route navigation, you can check: [Perform navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#perform-navigation).

Comment: Could you please help confirm if the solution is helpful to your question?